# Exponential list of numbers with the total sum equal to 100

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to generate an exponential (or linear) list of number (float or int) where the total sum = 100

More or less Like this one:

[2, 10, 18, 30, 40]    total sum = 100

For now, i use this code to generate exponential (or linear) list of numbers, but i dont know the formula to get numbers with a total sum = 100

```
import numpy as np
l = np.logspace(0.1, 2, 10, endpoint=True)
#OR
l = np.linspace(1, 100, 10, endpoint=True)
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: do you know how many numbers you want?

Comment: You should be able to generate an arbitrary list of values from an exponential sequence (`le = np.exp(l)`), then linearly scale the values using `np.sum(le)`. If I'm not mistaken, a linearly scaled exponential sequence is still an exponential sequence.

Comment: @André Indeed, since multiplication is associative. `(x*n)*s == x*(n*s)`.

Comment: @njzk2  I wish I could specify it as i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
target_norm = 100
l = np.linspace(0, 10, 21, endpoint=True)
le = np.exp(l)
le_normed = target_norm*(le/np.sum(le))
print(f'{np.sum(le_normed)}') # 100 (=target_norm)
```

By making the sampling interval of `l` larger, you can scale the exponential.

We already saw that `np.sum(le_normed) == target_norm` but let's check if the results look plausible:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close('all')
fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(12, 3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax.set_title("l")
ax.plot(l)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax.set_title('le')
ax.plot(le)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
ax.set_title('le_normed')
ax.plot(le_normed)
fig
```

[image: Visualization of the transformation]

Comment: Thanks you very much !
I just added a round(value , 2) to get readable number.